# how to clear text editing controller from another class

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

so i have two class, button and text field

this is text field with controller widget

[image: UjianEssaiWidget]

this is button action to clean my controllerTextEditing
[image: Button/Action Widget to clean my controllerTextEditing]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `GlobalKey` to accomplish this . Put the `TextFormField`  as a child to `Form`

```
GlobalKey<FormState> _key = GlobalKey<FormState>();

class MyForm extends StatelessWidget
{
MyForm({Key key}) : super(key:key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Form(
key: _key,
autovalidate: true,
child: // All the form fields will go here
);
 }
}
```

After that you can use

```
_key.currentState.reset()
```

in another class ,which will reset each field inside the form back to its `initialValue`

Comment: did my answer was helpful ? if it was then please accept/upvote the answer. If you have further query then ask in comments .

Comment: Sorry there was a typo , I had written _key.reset(), it should have been _key.currentState.reset()

Comment: How to exactly access this key from another class?