# How to reset all checkbox Items and data attached to it in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am implementing an app in flutter having checkboxes on the homepage. The user has a chance to select items from the list and then he can share. Everything is fine until now. but, after sharing I want to add a reset option to the user that he can start from the beginning. Like, Unchecking and resetting all items and related data to that checked items. How can I function my reset button to do this?

Comment: What did you try? Post the specific problem you are stuck at and a [mcve].

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655785/how-to-clear-text-editing-controller-from-another-class/63656285#63656285

Comment: @nvoigt, I need a reset button that can clear all previously checked items at ones

Comment: @gladiator, can I add a form field to checkboxlisttile widget. (checkboxlisttile is wrapped in a listview.builder)

Comment: That was not my question. I did not ask what you need. I asked where you are stuck. What is the line of code you need help with? Please provide a [mcve] and a specific question.

Comment: @nvoigt sorry to say this. I don't have any idea about what to write inside a reset button to get needed functionality. I haven't stuck in code. I need a way to do this. I searched in flutter docs for reset functionality but I haven't found.

Comment: you dont know what to implement means you haven't even implemented any basic functionality in flutter, start implementing, you come here when you are stuck, dont start from the middle, unchecking is as easy as setting every variable the maintains the state of the checkbox to false

Comment: @Yadu, I, Implemented an app that can have checkboxlist items and can share items. I haven't started in the middle. I, Implemented the app from the beginning. I know how to unchecking each item individually. but, I want to uncheck all items once by pressing the reset button.

Comment: how do you check or uncheck the box?? post that code

Comment: _checked = false;         value  = _checked;                                                                              
   onChanged: (bool newValue) {
              setState(() {
                _checked = newValue;}

Comment: I am not well in questioning. My problem is whenever the user hits the reset button app should start from the beginning. Like app opened from beginning

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask go here

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reset checkboxes or any other control widget by initializing them to their initial value in `onPressed` property of the ResetButton and calling `setState((){})` . See the code below on how to do that:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  MyFormState createState() => MyFormState();
}

class MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  bool checkBoxValue1 = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          "CheckBox1 Value : $checkBoxValue1",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        Form(
          child: FormField<bool>(
            initialValue: false,
            builder: (FormFieldState<bool> state) {
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Checkbox(
                    value: checkBoxValue1,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      checkBoxValue1 = value;
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                  ),
                  const Text("Check Box 1")
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: const Text("Reset"),
          onPressed: () {
           //Reset All Checkboxes

            checkBoxValue1 = false;
            //checkBoxValue2 = false;
            //checkBoxValue3 = false;
            //checkBoxValue4 = false;
            setState(() {});
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

You can also provide a `GlobalKey<FormState> _key` to `Form` , if you have many textfields , radiobuttons etc and want to reset them to their initial value , just call `_key.currentState.reset()` .